# Setting up multiple iterative statement

Tags: python

Let me say I'm rather new to python and stack overflow, so please help out if I'm making mistakes while I'm posting here.

I have a set of data where I am building intervals in a loop.

The data consists of three columns (0's and 1's). I would like to start a new interval any time a new 1 appears (where all three data sets are 0 before) and close the interval right before all elements are 0 again. For example:

```
data = [[0. 0. 0.]
        [1. 0. 0.]
        [1. 1. 0.]
        [1. 1. 1.]
        [0. 1. 1.]
        [0. 0. 1.]
        [0. 0. 0.]]
```

should come out as one interval with:

```
intervals = [[[1. 0. 0.]
              [1. 1. 0.]
              [1. 1. 1.]
              [0. 1. 1.]
              [0. 0. 1.]]]
```

and if there was the pattern in data was to repeat or there was a new sequence (following the same rules) , it would start a new interval. As an example, if the data set had the same repeating information, intervals would become:

```
intervals = [[[1. 0. 0.]
              [1. 1. 0.]
              [1. 1. 1.]
              [0. 1. 1.]
              [0. 0. 1.]],
             [[1. 0. 0.]
              [1. 1. 0.]
              [1. 1. 1.]
              [0. 1. 1.]
              [0. 0. 1.]] ]
```

I able to achieve this style for an array of values with the following code, but am now trying to extend it to a n x 3 format.

```
A = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
b = [[A[0]]]
last_char = A[0]
num_seq = 0
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if A[i] != last_char:
        num_seq += 1
    if len(b) <= num_seq:
        b.append([])
    b[num_seq].append(A[i])
    last_char = A[i]
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: First of all, this is an invalid data structure. Secondly, you shoyld show what you've tried.

Comment: That code is invalid, please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working. It is an extension of the last part of information I have in my statement. If anyone has anything more clean, I'd love to see it.

```
if data[0].any() == 1:
    last_char = 1
    access_matrix = [[1]]
else:
    last_char = 0
    access_matrix = [[0]]

num_seq = 0

for i in range(1, len(data)):
    if data[i].any() == 1:
        temp_var = 1
    else:
        temp_var = 0
    if temp_var != last_char:
        num_seq += 1
    if len(access_matrix) <= num_seq:
        access_matrix.append([])
    access_matrix[num_seq].append(temp_var)
    last_char = temp_var
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know the context of the problem required for the code but here's the code which gives you the result that you are looking for.

```
data = [0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 
        1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0,]
idx=0
result=[]
temp_list=[]
for i in data:
    if idx <= len(data)-1:
        ele = data[idx]
        if ele ==0:
            if idx%3==0:
                if data[idx+1] == 0  and data[idx+2] == 0:
                    # break the interval
                    if temp_list:
                        result.append(temp_list)
                    temp_list=[]
                    idx+=3
                else:
                    # add ele to interval
                    temp_list.append(ele)
                    idx+=1
            else:
                # add ele to interval
                temp_list.append(ele)
                idx+=1
        else:
           # add ele to interval
            temp_list.append(ele)
            idx+=1
print(result)
```

The result is a list of your intervals found.

```
[
  [
   1, 0, 0,
   1, 1, 0, 
   1, 1, 1, 
   0, 1, 1, 
   0, 0, 1
  ]
]
```

Comment: This is close to what I need but as others have stated, my types that I have given were incorrect. I've updated with more information and if this isn't quite clear enough, I threw in what I have for a one-dimensional case. Hopefully this clears things up.